# Why interrupt is not triggered?

Tags: pic, interrupts, xc8

When pin RB5 changes between high and low it should trigger interrupt. Interrupt happens when IC gets powered and does not occur afterwards when RB5 gets connected or disconnected from vdd. Why so?

I am using PIC16F677-I/P

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSCIO oscillator: I/O function on RA4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled and can be enabled by SWDTEN bit of the WDTCON register)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select bit (MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Selection bits (BOR enabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

void main(void)
{
    // Select 8 MHz internal oscillator
    IRCF2 = 1;
    IRCF1 = 1;
    IRCF0 = 1;

    // High Frequency Internal Oscillator is stable
    HTS = 1;

    // Use internal oscillator for system clock
    SCS = 1;

    // Global interrupt enable
    GIE = 1;

    // PORTA/B change interrupt enable
    RABIE = 1;

    RABIF = 0;

    // RB5 as digital input
    ANS11 = 0;

    // RB5 as input
    TRISB5 = 1;

    // RB5 interrupt on change
    IOCB5 = 1;

    // RC6 as output
    TRISC6 = 0;

    RC6 = 0;

    while (true)
    {

    }
}

void interrupt myintrout(void)
{
    if (RABIF)
    {
        RC6 = RC6 ? 0 : 1;
        RABIF = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the interrupt is not immediately re-triggering. You must clear the miss-match condition by either reading or writing PORTB prior to clearing RABIF per page 69 of the [PIC16F677 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262d.pdf)

Comment: @Tut I have tried RB5 = 0; before RABIF = 0; if that is what you mean.

Comment: Read the datasheet and then try reading PORTB. Note RB5 is an input not an output. Leave it in there because you will need it whether that is the only thing wrong or not.

Comment: Not related to the question, but RC6 = !RC6; is more readable than RC6 = RC6 ? 0 : 1;.  I had to think about that for a few seconds before I saw what you were doing.

Comment: @AaronD Yea, thanks, I do not know why I used this form when posted question.

Comment: I agree with Tut.  I don't see why it's not immediately re-triggering either.  But you do have to *read* the port before clearing the interrupt flag.  The reason is that there's a hidden register that gets updated as a side-effect of reading the port, and the interrupt logic looks for a difference between the port and that register.

Comment: @Tut Not sure where are you going with that note about RB5. As for reading datasheet, I cannot find what I am missing.

Comment: @Tut Ah, now I get it. RB5 = 0; is assigning value to input pin. But still, I have tried to read PORTB into variable and that does not help.

Answer (score 1):

When RC6 = !RC6; is used, first high on RB5 makes RC6 high. At this point no changes can be made to RC6 after making RB5 high or low.

When I use RC6 = RB5; I can observe interruptions.